# Print only those arrays with 3 digits whose sum is 10 - C program

Tags: c, arrays, recursion

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 
1 2 7 
1 3 6 
1 4 5 
1 9 
2 3 5 
2 8 
3 7 
4 6 
10
```

Expected Output:

```
1 2 7 
1 3 6 
1 4 5 
2 3 5
```

I want only those pairs of digits whose sum is 10 and also has only 3 digits i.e, the pair of 3 distinct digits whose sum is 10 should be displayed, rest all other pairs get skip or not displayed.

Below is my full source code which I have written for this problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void partition(int part) {
    int *parts, *ptr, i, idx = 0, tot = 0, cur = 1, max = 1;   

    while ((max * (max + 1)) / 2 <= part)
        max++;`

    ptr = parts = malloc(sizeof(int) * max);

    for (;;) {
        if ((tot += *ptr++ = cur++) < part)
            continue;

        if (tot == part) {
            for (i = 0; i < ptr-parts; i++) {
                printf("%d ", parts[i]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }

        do {
            if (ptr == parts) {
                free(parts);
                return;
            }
            tot -= cur = *--ptr;
        } while (++cur + tot > part);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char*argv[]) {
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    partition(n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your question is confusing: do you want all possible triplets of distinct positive numbers with a given sum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code seems way too complicated. Here is a simple solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SUM 10

int main(void) {
    for(int a = 1; a < SUM; a++) {
        for(int b = a + 1; b < SUM; b++) {
            for(int c = b + 1; c < SUM; c++) {
                if(a + b + c == SUM) {
                    printf("%d %d %d\n", a, b, c);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Program output:

```
1 2 7
1 3 6
1 4 5
2 3 5
```

This could be more efficient but it is a simple form.

Comment: Just trying to walk round the mountain not climb over it! If you are entering the number of values to sum, a recursive solution would be better, but the task is unclear.

Comment: At this point I would try doing: `puts("1 2 7");puts("1 3 6");puts("1 4 5");puts(2 3 5");`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is too generic for this problem: you do not need to enumerate all possible partitions and select those with 3 numbers. Just enumerate all possible triplets without duplicates.

Here is a simpler and much faster solution for your problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void partition(int sum) {
    /* enumerate a, b, c such that:
       a < b < c
       a + b + c = sum
    */
    int a, b;
    for (a = 1; 3 * a + 2 <= sum; a++) {
        for (b = a + 1; a + 2 * b + 1 <= sum; b++) {
            printf("%d %d %d\n", a, b, sum - a - b);
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int n;
    if (scanf("%d", &n) == 1)
        partition(n);
    return 0;
}
```