# Check at least 2 numbers are perfect squares - c program

Tags: c, loops, recursion, conditional-statements

Output:

```
1 2 9
1 3 8
1 4 7
1 5 6
2 3 7
2 4 6
3 4 5
```

Expected:

```
1 2 9
1 4 7
```

I only want to print those arrays which have at least 2 perfect squares in them. 
In the above output, "1 2 9" 1 & 9 are perfect squares, as are 1 and 4. The remaining results get skip or don't print.

Below is my current code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(void) {
int num;
scanf("%d",&num);
if(num<200)
for(int a = 1; a < num; a++) {
    for(int b = a + 1; b < num; b++) {
        for(int c = b + 1; c < num; c++) {
            if(a + b + c == num) {
                printf("%d %d %d\n", a, b, c);
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: "I only want to print those arrays which have at least 2 perfect squares in it." So what's stopping you from doing that?

Comment: That was the code I posted in your [recent question about sums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51689028/print-only-those-arrays-with-3-digits-whose-sum-is-10-c-program), but you made no attempt here to solve perfect squares.

Comment: Do you not know how to check if a number is a perfect square? The code you posted simply lists all sets of three different numbers that sum to the inputted value.

Comment: I'm new to programming, please support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a pretty simple task, you just need to check for every `{a,b,c}` if there are at least two squares in it. It is maybe not the best method to check if a number is a square, but you can write your own function to check it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int is_square(int x)
{
    for(int i=1;i<=x/i;i++)
    {
        if(i*i==x)
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    int num;
    scanf("%d",&num);
    if(num<200)
    {
        for(int a = 1; a < num; a++)
        {
            for(int b = a + 1; b < num; b++)
            {
                for(int c = b + 1; c < num; c++)
                {
                    if(a + b + c == num && is_square(a) + is_square(b) + is_square(c) >= 2)
                    {
                        printf("%d %d %d\n", a, b, c);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of another for loop, could you see if x/x = round(x/x)? This is the logic I would use, but I'm used to other languages, so more curious than anything else.

Comment: @NathanStockton `x/x` will always evaluate to `1` for integers except `0`.

Comment: @NathanStockton I think you meant `sqrt(x) == floor(sqrt(x))`?

Comment: Ok, so you cant get a float value? Could you chexh if sqrt(x)%1=0? I have always avoided using a for loop to evaluate mathematical problems where possible.

Comment: @NathanStockton checking if two floats or doubles are equal is not a good idea because of rounding errors. [See this](https://onlinegdb.com/r1qPJhmS7).

Comment: `i*i` in `for(int i=1;i*i<=x;i++)` may overflow.  `for(int i=1;i<=x/i; i++)` does not.